# Font type used zStartUp Theme from zerotheme.com

Tags: fonts

Im thinking of using zStartUp Theme from zerotheme.com but I cant identify the font type being used?

http://www.zerotheme.com/484/zstartup-free-responsive-html5-theme.html

Anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Try Bilbo ROB - https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typesetit/bilbo/regular/

or maybe LD Grandpa - https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/lettering-delights/ld-grandpa/regular/

These are very similar but not exact matches. Try them out.